# Group By PurchaseOrderNumber, AccountNumber, ProductType Order By InsertionTimestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a large table of orders that are grouped by PurchaseOrderNumber, AccountNumber, and ProductType when processed.  The client is requesting us to process these orders based on the InsertionTimestamp.

Here is the query we where using which works fine but needs to be changed at the clients request.

```
Select Purchase_Order_Number, Account_Number, Max(LineNumber) LineNumber, Product_Type 
From dbo.PDF_Orders_Validation 
Where BotReady = 'Y' 
Group By Purchase_Order_Number, Account_Number, Product_Type
```

What I've tried that doesn't work...

```
Select Purchase_Order_Number, Account_Number, Max(LineNumber) LineNumber, Product_Type
From dbo.PDF_Orders_Validation 
Where BotReady = '' 
Group By Purchase_Order_Number, Account_Number, Product_Type
Order By InsertionTimestamp
```

I've also tried this...

```
Select Purchase_Order_Number, Account_Number, Max(LineNumber) LineNumber, Product_Type
From dbo.PDF_Orders_Validation 
Where BotReady = '' 
Group By Purchase_Order_Number, Account_Number, Product_Type, InsertionTimestamp
Order By InsertionTimestamp
```

...which works but creates too many lines and can potentially cause duplicate orders.

What I need is to retain the original query but just re-order the lines in ascending order by InsertionTimestamp.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to illustrate what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
Select Purchase_Order_Number, Account_Number, Max(LineNumber) LineNumber, Product_Type
From dbo.PDF_Orders_Validation 
Where BotReady = '' 
Group By Purchase_Order_Number, Account_Number, Product_Type
Order By MAX(InsertionTimestamp)
```

Note -- not sure of your processing pipeline so it might be that you want MIN() not MAX()